# application of Time, speed and distance

Tags: algebra-precalculus

At the ancient Athens Olympic games, in a duel between two runners, Portheus and Morpheus, they were made to start running in opposite direction from diametrically opposite ends of a circular race track
of length (circumference) 2 kms. The first time they met was after 24 minutes. If the distance between
them exactly ‘n’ minutes after they start is equal to a quarter of the length of the track, which of the
following is a possible value of ‘n’?

I just don't understand this question therefore unable to make equation from this, this question is based upon application of time, speed and distance. I would appreciate if someone explain me this visually i don't want answer i just want to know how to approach this. My basics of time, speed and distance are clear but this question gives me hard time.

Comment: Here's a hint:
if x is Portheus' speed in meters / minute, and y is Morpheus' speed in meters/minute.
What is the combined distance they run after 24 minutes? Draw it out and you'll see it's easy to figure out. From there the rest shouldn't be too hard.

Answer (score 1):

Since they meet, it is clear that they don't have the same speed. Rather than thinking of both of them moving, consider one of them (say Portheus) to be faster by some amount x. Now the situation can be thought of as Morpheus staying still, and Portheus running with that speed x. So essentially, Portheus covered half the circumference (the initial distance between them) in 24 minutes. This gives you how much faster Portheus is compared to Morpheus

Can you take it from here?